# How to understand that $\min(a,b) < c \Leftrightarrow a < c \text{ or } b < c$ and $\max(a,b) < c \Leftrightarrow a < c \text{ and } b < c$??

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, logic, intuition

In many probability related questions, I need to find the the probability of

$P[\min(X_1,X_2) < c]$

where $X_1, X_2$ are random variables

---

However, I can never remember this basic relationship:

given any real numbers $a,b,c$, we have that $\min(a,b) < c \Leftrightarrow a < c \text{ or } b < c$.

Ditto, $\max(a,b) < c \Leftrightarrow a < c \text{ and } b < c$.

I have looked up the explanation and people basically said this is just "logic".

---

I guess my problem is not understanding what $\min(a,b) < c$ means.

To me, it means pick a number less than $c$ that is either $a$ **or** $b$, and show me the smaller of the two.

*Aha, that must be where the "or" come from.*

But wait a minute, it is also true that $\max(a,b) < c \Leftrightarrow a < c \text{ and } b < c$.

In this case, we also have: pick a number less than $c$ that is either $a$ or $b$, and show me the larger of the two.

Now where would the "and" come from?

---

All in all, is there a more rigorous way of showing that this is true?

Comment: "The shortest of us is less than 6 feet tall" = "at least one of us is least than 6 feet tall".  Is that more intuitive?  Are you looking for a formal proof?

Comment: You could think of the minimum one as: "$\min(a,b)<c$ if and only if $\min(a,b,c)<c$, if and only if $a<c$ or $b<c.$"

Comment: Also analogous to DanielV example: "The tallest of us is less than 6 feet tall"="all of us are less than 6 feet tall". My problem is you are Brad Pitt with Matt Damon profile picture and asking about logic.

Comment: “To me, it means pick a number less than c that is either $a$ or $b$ … Aha, that must be where the or come from.” You are right. $a<c\lor a<b$ is deduced from $\min(a, b)=a \lor \min(a, b)=b$, and other properties of $\min$ are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess my problem is not understanding what $\min(a,b) < c$ means.
>
> To me, it means pick a number less than $c$ that is either $a$ **or** $b$, and show me the smaller of the two.
>
> *Aha, that must be where the "or" come from.*

Indeed, $\min\{a,b\}< c$ means that the lesser of the two values is less than $c$; so one of them is but the other might not be.   Therefore $a<c$ *or* $b<c$.

$$a\leq b<c,\\ a<c\leq b,\\ b<a<c,\\ b<c\leq a.$$

> But wait a minute, it is also true that $\max(a,b) < c \Leftrightarrow a < c \text{ and } b < c$.
>
> In this case, we also have: pick a number less than $c$ that is either $a$ or $b$, and show me the larger of the two.
>
> Now where would the "and" come from?

$\max\{a,b\}<c$ means that the greater of the two values is less than $c$, and if the greater is then the lesser also must be too.   Hence, it means that both values are less than $c$   Therefore $a<c$ *and* $b<c$.

$$a\leq b<c,\\b<a<c.$$

Answer (score 2):

I think of $\min(a,b)<c$ to mean that "the smaller number of $a$ and $b$ is less than $c$. I think of $\max(a,b)<c$ to mean that "the largest number out of $a$ and $b$ is less than $c$. If you think of it this way, then it becomes quite clear: if the smallest number out of $a$ and $b$ is less than $c$ then this means at least one of them is less than $c$, so either $a<c$ or $b<c$. If the largest number out of $a$ and $b$ is less than $c$, then since it is the largest of the two, the other one is less than this maximum number, so they musts both be less that $c$.

---

More rigorously:

Suppose $a<b$. Then $\min(a,b)=a$, and since $\min(a,b)<c$, we have that $a<c$.
**Alternatively**, $b<a$. Then $\min(a,b)=b$, and since $\min(a,b)<c$, we have that $b<c$.
(Also, if $a=b$, then $\min(a,b)=a=b<c$, so this still holds)
So we have determined that if $\min(a,b)<c$, then either $a<c$ or $b<c$.

Using similar reasoning you can determine that the backward implication also holds.

For the $\max$ case, the proof is very similar, but the word I have in **bold** above, *alternatively*, becomes *also*.

Answer (score 2):

Visualising numbers on an axis, it's obvious:

- The first assertion means the leftmost of $a$ and $b$ is left of $c$ if and only if one of $a$ and $b$ is left of $c$.
- The second assertion means the rightmost of $a$ and $b$ is left of $c$ if and only if both $a$ and $b$ are left of $c$.